# Wordpress esc_textarea() deletes line breaks, how to keep them?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using a plugin called Meta Sliders and I'd like my captions to keep the new line I input when I write them.

I found the function that I think prints the text: $caption = esc_textarea( $this->slide->post_excerpt );

I've read that the esc_textarea() removes the line breaks... How can I keep them?

Thanks!

Comment: The thing is, when I view the code, there are line breaks, but just in plan text, no <p> no <br> no nothing...

Answer (score 0):

One dirty way I can think of, is first str_replace the line break to something else (for example [br]) then do the esc_textarea and then str_replace [br] back to line breaks. Not pretty and maybe not the best way, but it works.

Comment: I didn't fully understand but, I can input html tags like <br> and they work, but I need not to use them, as it's for a client's website.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <?php wp_kses(nl2br($this->slide->post_excerpt), array('br'=>array())); ?>
```

Comment: Where? In the same php file that generates the captions?

Comment: instead  esc_textarea( $this->slide->post_excerpt )

Comment: Weird. Now, if I add a line break on the edit area and save it, nothing happens... but if I reload the page where the edit area is, it adds the <br /> tags there, and then of course there are line breaks on the slider's captions, but that's a strange behaviour and non acceptable for a client.

Thanks for the idea though! I guess without looking a all the code it's difficult to guess where to add this function...